# Boostrap CSS How to make span, input text, checkbox in one line?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, bootstrap-4

[image]Hi

I using css and boostrap.
I have a span, input, checkbox  which i want to put into one line.
But it came out like in the picture. The checkbox drop down to second line.

Here is the code.

```html
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 textfield">

                            <label>
                                <span style="width: 55%; display:inline-block;" type="text" class="display-control backgroundcolor" value="">Gym<span style="color: Red; font-weight:800;font-size:larger;">*</span></span>
                                <input style="width: 33%; display: inline-block; text-align: right;" type="number" id="Amount" name="Amount" class="form-control" value="0.00">
                                <label class="checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox__control" name="Facilities" data="Gym" id="F011">
                                    <span style="float: right; width: 11%;" class="checkbox__label"> </span>
                                </label>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 textfield">
                                    <label>
                                        <span style="width: 55%; display:inline-block;" type="text" class="display-control backgroundcolor" value="">Mall<span style="color: Red; font-weight:800;font-size:larger;">*</span></span>
                                        <input style="width: 33%; display:inline-block; text-align:right;" type="number" id="Amount" name="Amount" class="form-control" value="0.00">
                                        <label class="checkbox">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox__control" name="Facilities" data="Mall*" id="F012">
                                            <span style="float: right; width: 11%;" class="checkbox__label"> </span>
                                        </label>
                                    </label>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Hope someone can help on this. Thank

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="checkbox__control">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox__control" id="exampleCheck1">
    <label class="checkbox__control" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
</div>
```

try this one . .

Comment: Tried, not help because The check box disappear.